# Xamarin.Forms webview not showing responsive html from url

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms

Here is my code.
Though the site is responsive, the ui is not showing correctly.The width is not showing like responsive site in a browser.

```
<WebView Source="http://www.classroomdj.com" x:Name="webView"    

      Navigated="webOnEndNavigated"
      Navigating="webOnNavigating"
      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
  />
```

Comment: Is the site showing at all or is it just a blank screen?

Comment: the site is showing inside webview but its not scaling down the width, size by device with.

Comment: Can you post the html or provide a link to the site. The WebView normally displays responsive html just fine, hence I think it might be an issue with your html.

Comment: Ah, ok if its ClassroomDJ, then I just tested that and can see what you mean. The WebView isn't exactly the same as the browser and has all kinds of wonderful quirks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ClassroomDJ.com add the viewport tag in the  tags

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

To allow proper scaling on a mobile browser. The WebViews in the mobile OS are not as powerful as the regular browsers on mobile devices and are normally a limited subset that needs more information to work properly. The regular browsers always try to take care of a huge amount of edge cases to give the user the best experience possible.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the viewport meta tag was there.Your answer fixed my problem.After that I have to apply some responsive css fixings to images.